# Check if element in a list

Tags: python, list

I want to check if the string that is given through parameters in the function is in a list. The code itself doesn't produce any errors but it works the wrong way. If I give my function "-a" as parameter it still says that it's not in the list but it definitely is.

This is the code :

```
def generatePassword(pLength, mode):
    password = str()
    commands = ["-a", "-n", "-s", "-allupper", "-mixupper"]
    alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p",
                "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
    specialCharacters = ["!", "?", "&", "@",
                         "-", "=", "#", "+", "*", "/", "%", "§"]
    if mode.lower().split() not in commands:
        print("Couldn't recognize commands...")
    else:
        for n in range(pLength):
            i = random.randint(1, 2)
            if "-a" in mode.lower().split():
                password += alphabet[random.randint(0, 25)]
        print("[+]", password)

generatePassword(30, "-a")
```

Comment: Your first `if` line asks if a list is in another list, this will never be true for non-nested lists, even if the lists are identical

Comment: When you `split` a string, the output will be a list. As the list is not there in `commands`, it is returning `False`. Drop the `split()` to fix this.

Comment: @thefourtheye A mere dropping of `spilt()` is not a solution. There might be more than command.

Comment: @thefourtheye I tried dropping it but if I do so I won't be able to use more than one command..

Comment: You don't need `alphabet` (use the builtin `string.lowercase`) or `specialCharacters` (use the builtin `string.punctuation`)

Comment: Oh right. You need to split and process it. I would recommend [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) to deal with all these command line arguments problems.

Comment: If you want to pass more than one `mode`, it is probably easier if you use a tuple:  `def generatePassword(pLength, *mode):` and then:  `generatePassword(30, "-a ","-n", "-s")`.  Then convert the tuple to a `set`.

Comment: @cdarke I didn't learn about sets yet so I don't know how to implement them. Thanks for sharing the idea though :)

Comment: ...and if you want to generate one random lowercase letter, use `random.sample(string.lowercase, 1) [0]`

Comment: Also, what is `i = random.randint(1, 2)`, you never use it?

Comment: @smci I use this variable in later modes where I generate randomly mixed letters and numbers (It randomizes the order). My code wasn't at that point when I pasted it in here. And for your solution for my need of the alphabet list : I am quite new to python and I didn't read all the inbuilt module docs yet..Thanks for pointing those methods out though I will consider using them in my code it definitely saves up a lot of lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `any` command to check if any of the words in `mode.lower().split()` are not in commands:

```
def generatePassword(pLength, mode):
    password = str()
    commands = ["-a", "-n", "-s", "-allupper", "-mixupper"]
    alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p",
                "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
    specialCharacters = ["!", "?", "&", "@",
                         "-", "=", "#", "+", "*", "/", "%", "§"]

    if any(x not in commands for x in mode.lower().split()):
        print("Couldn't recognize commands...")
    else:
        for n in range(pLength):
            i = random.randint(1, 2)
            if "-a" in mode.lower().split():
                password += alphabet[random.randint(0, 25)]
        print("[+]", password)

generatePassword(30, "-a")
```

Comment: This way it won't let me use more than one command in the parameter. That's why I splitted it up :/

Comment: @hudumudu Check the answer now! You can use the `any` command to see if any of the words in `mode.lower().split()` are not in commands.

Comment: This worked as well thanks! Can I accept more than one answer as correct in Stackoverflow?

Comment: @hudumudu Unfortunately not, but do up vote all that you felt were helpful (y). Actually maybe you don't have enough rep to do that but it is alright, just pick whichever answer you feel is better suited to your question. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Your condition is not good:

```
if mode.lower().split() not in commands:
    print("Couldn't recognize commands...")
```

Replace it by (for example):

```
args = set(mode.lower().split())
if not set(args).issubset(set(commands)):
    print("Couldn't recognize commands...")
```

http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/Test-if-list-contains-another-list-td1506964.html

Comment: This worked for me thanks! I didn't learn about sets yet so I didn't know when and how to implement them but I'll take a look at them soon.

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
mode.lower().split()
```

to

```
mode.lower()
```